# How do we obtain that $(n|z|)^2-n|z|-1 \leq 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am looking at the following proof:

**Lemma.**

Let $n>1$. Suppose the following conditions $(9)$, $(10)$, $(11)$, and $(12)$ hold: 
$$(9) \ \ \ \ nz+nx-1  \mid_n n^2u-(nx-1)^2  \\ 
(10) \ \ \ \ 2nz+1  \mid_n nx-1  \\  
(11) \ \ \ \ 2nz-1  \mid_n nx-1  \\ 
(12) \ \ \ \ 2n^2u+1  \mid_n nx-1 $$

Then $u=z^2$.

[image]

$$$$

---

$$$$

How do we obtain from $(13)$, $(14)$ and $(15)$ $$(n|z|)^2-n|z|-1 \leq 0\ ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add (14) to (15) to obtain
$$4n^2 z^2 + 2n^2 |u| - 2 \leq 2|nx-1|$$
Divide both sides by $2$:
$$2n^2 z^2 + n^2|u| - 1 \leq |nx-1|$$
Subtract $n|z|$ from both sides to obtain
$$2n^2 z^2 + n^2|u| - n|z| - 1 \leq |nx-1| - n|z|$$
The RHS of this last inequality is the same as the LHS of (13), so the LHS of this inequality is $\leq$ the RHS of (13):
$$2n^2 z^2 + n^2|u| - n|z| - 1 \leq n^2|u| + n^2 z^2$$
Now subtract $n^2|u| + n^2 z^2$ from both sides to obtain
$$n^2 z^2 - n|z| - 1 \leq 0$$

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-)